# Is there a flag/property to identify custom content types?

Tags: content-type

Is there a flag / property to identify custom content types in SharePoint 2010 ?
I know when creating new content types its possible to put them in a group (for exc. custom content types), but is it somehow possible to find out if existing content types are out of the box or custom created ? 
I mean is there something like a flag or property that can be queried with powershell/console application to find out if a content type is custom ?

Thanks a lot for answers !

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I thought I'd post a possible solution here for anyone looking.

There is no such flag and using `SPBuiltInContentTypeId` is not sufficient because it doesn't include all built in content types.

Based on the SharePoint 2013 content types [here](http://www.jkevinparker.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-content-types-and.html) I've cobbled this together. I've run this on my own farm and the only content types I got back that weren't user-created were SQL Server Reporting Services ones. The list of content types was small enough for me to manually filter these out.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

Function global:Get-SPWebApplication($WebAppURL)
{
    return [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($WebAppURL)
}

Function global:Write-File($contenttype, $url)
{    
    foreach ($ct in $allcts)
    {
        $isCustomCT = $true

        if ($contenttype.Id.ToString() -eq $ct)
        {
            $isCustomCT = $false
            break            
        }        
    }

    if ($isCustomCT -eq $true)
    {
        "$($contenttype.Name)`t$($contenttype.ID)`t$($url)`t$($contenttype.Group))"  | Out-File $File -append
    }    
}

$allcts = "0x"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA0884"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088401"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088402"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088403"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088404"`
    ,"0x01"`
    ,"0x01000F389E14C9CE4CE486270B9D4713A5D6"`
    ,"0x010018F21907ED4E401CB4F14422ABC65304"`
    ,"0x010019ACC57FBA4146AFA4C822E719824BED"`
    ,"0x010027FC2137D8DE4B00A40E14346D070D52"`
    ,"0x010027FC2137D8DE4B00A40E14346D070D5201"`
    ,"0x01002A2479FF33DD4BC3B1533A012B653717"`
    ,"0x01002CF74A4DAE39480396EEA7A4BA2BE5FB"`
    ,"0x01003A8AA7A4F53046158C5ABD98036A01D5"`
    ,"0x01004613D6562E4C41A7B9DADDAC1689E00D"`
    ,"0x01004C9F4486FBF54864A7B0A33D02AD19B1"`
    ,"0x01004D5A79BAFA4A4576B79C56FF3D0D662D"`
    ,"0x01007CE30DD1206047728BAFD1C39A850120"`
    ,"0x0100807FBAC5EB8A4653B8D24775195B5463"`
    ,"0x010085EC78BE64F9478AAE3ED069093B9963"`
    ,"0x010087D89D279834C94E98E5E1B4A913C67E"`
    ,"0x01009AF87C5C1DF34CA38277FEABCB5018F6"`
    ,"0x01009BE2AB5291BF4C1A986910BD278E4F18"`
    ,"0x0100A2CA87FF01B442AD93F37CD7DD0943EB"`
    ,"0x0100AA27A923036E459D9EF0D18BBD0B9587"`
    ,"0x0100C30DDA8EDB2E434EA22D793D9EE42058"`
    ,"0x0100CA13F2F8D61541B180952DFB25E3E8E4"`
    ,"0x0100DC2417D125A4489CA59DCC70E3F152B2"`
    ,"0x0100F95DB3A97E8046B58C6A54FB31F2BD46"`
    ,"0x0100FBEEE6F0C500489B99CDA6BB16C398F7"`
    ,"0x0101"`
    ,"0x01010000DEC92EFE5D445789D9FE4A3225A381"`
    ,"0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC1"`
    ,"0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811"`
    ,"0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE8110003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3B"`
    ,"0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F"`
    ,"0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F0054AD6EF48B9F7B45A142F8173F171BD1"`
    ,"0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F0054AD6EF48B9F7B45A142F8173F171BD10003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3A"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F3851066"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106601"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106602"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106604"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106605"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F3851068"`
    ,"0x01010058DDEB47312E4967BFC1576B96E8C3D4"`
    ,"0x010100629D00608F814DD6AC8A86903AEE72AA"`
    ,"0x010100734778F2B7DF462491FC91844AE431CF"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00291D173ECE694D56B19D111489C4369D"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B006973ACD696DC4858A76371B2FB2F439A"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214"`
    ,"0x010100A2E3C117A0C5482FAEE3D57C48CB042F"`
    ,"0x010100B4CBD48E029A4AD8B62CB0E41868F2B0"`
    ,"0x010100C5033D6CFB8447359FB795C8A73A2B19"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C0055EF50AAFF2E4BADA437E4BAE09A30F8"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900796F542FC5E446758C697981E370458C"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900B46186789C3140CC85BE610336E86BBB"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900FD0E870BA06948879DBD5F9813CD8799"`
    ,"0x010100E8711F0F931646FA949751442A907B22"`
    ,"0x010100F8EF98760CBA4A94994F13BA881038FA"`
    ,"0x010100FDA260FD09A244B183A666F2AE2475A6"`
    ,"0x010101"`
    ,"0x010102"`
    ,"0x010104"`
    ,"0x010105"`
    ,"0x010106"`
    ,"0x010107"`
    ,"0x010108"`
    ,"0x010109"`
    ,"0x01010901"`
    ,"0x01010A"`
    ,"0x01010B"`
    ,"0x0102"`
    ,"0x0102004F51EFDEA49C49668EF9C6744C8CF87D"`
    ,"0x01020072BB2A38F0DB49C3A96CF4FA85529956"`
    ,"0x0102007DBDC1392EAF4EBBBF99E41D8922B264"`
    ,"0x0103"`
    ,"0x0104"`
    ,"0x0105"`
    ,"0x0106"`
    ,"0x0107"`
    ,"0x0108"`
    ,"0x0108003365C4474CAE8C42BCE396314E88E51F"`
    ,"0x010801"`
    ,"0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160"`
    ,"0x010802"`
    ,"0x0109"`
    ,"0x010A"`
    ,"0x010B"`
    ,"0x010C"`
    ,"0x0110"`
    ,"0x0111"`
    ,"0x0116"`
    ,"0x0120"`
    ,"0x012001"`
    ,"0x012002"`
    ,"0x012004"`
    ,"0x0120D5"`
    ,"0x0120D520"`
    ,"0x0120D520A8"`
    ,"0x0120D520A808"


#Get the SharePoint Farm. Equallent to : Get-SPFarm commandlet
$Farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local

#Get All feature of the farm. Equallent to: Get-SPFeature commandlet
$FarmFeatures= $Farm.FeatureDefinitions

$File = Read-Host("Enter the path of the file")

$WebAppURL = Read-Host("Enter your WebApp URL here")
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

#Scan Web Application Features
#Write the Header to "Tab Separated File"
"CT Name`tCT ID`tURL`tCT Group" | out-file $File

foreach($ctype in $WebApp.ContentTypes)
{
    Write-File $ctype $WebAppURL
}

#Get All site collections of the Web Application  
$SitesColl = $webApp.Sites

#Iterate through each site collection/sub-site
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
    #Iterate through each content type at Site collection level
    foreach($ctype in $site.ContentTypes)
    {
        Write-File $ctype $site.Url
    }

    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        #Iterate through each content type at web level
        foreach($ctype in $web.ContentTypes)
        {
            Write-File $ctype $Web.Url
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[SPBuiltInContentTypeID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltincontenttypeid.aspx): A class that retrieves SPContentTypeId objects that represent identifiers (IDs) for built-in content types.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such flag/property. But luckily built in content type ids are documented:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltincontenttypeid_members.aspx

You can use it to compare your content type's id to determine if its custom or OTB.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing my custom content type id with the list of avaliable SPBuiltInContentTypeIDs doesnt seem to work - there are a lot more built-in content types that have not been documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltincontenttypeid_members.aspx

for eg: video, audio, indicaors, reports - these are available OOTB with SP, but are not listed in the above link.