# Pulling information about custom content types

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-content-type

I've been asked to pull information and document all custom content types for an entire SharePoint 2010 farm. There are many sites and web applications so I was wondering if there was a way to pull all that information at once or if I have to do it on a site by site basis.

Comment: This has been up for SharePoint 2013, and there were a powershell script provided as well that might work for 2010. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31770/is-there-a-flag-property-to-identify-custom-content-types

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is iterate over all the site collection for each web application and get the content types

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

## Variables
$WEB_APPLICATION_URL = "http://teamsite"
$CTS_FILE_PATH = "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2013_TeamSite_ContentTypes.csv"
$FIELDS_FILE_PATH = "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2013_TeamSite_Fields.csv"
$CT_FIELDS_FILE_PATH = "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2013_TeamSite_CTs_And_Fields.csv"


## Initialization
echo "Initializing variables"
'"CT Name","CT Description","CT ID","CT Group","CT Parent ID"' | Out-File $CTS_FILE_PATH;
'"Field Title","Field Description","Field Internal Name","Field ID","Field Group","Field Type"' | Out-File $FIELDS_FILE_PATH;
'"CT Name","Field Title","CT ID","Field ID"' | Out-File $CT_FIELDS_FILE_PATH;

$AllContentTypes = @();
$AllFields = @();


## Go with the code
echo "Entering web application $WEB_APPLICATION_URL" 

$webApplication = Get-SPWebApplication -identity $WEB_APPLICATION_URL

ForEach ($siteCollection in $webApplication.Sites)
{
    ForEach($subSite in $siteCollection.AllWebs)
    {
        $subsiteUrl = $subsite.Url;

        echo "Extracting info from $subSiteUrl";

        $contentTypes = $subSite.ContentTypes;

        ForEach ($contentType in $contentTypes)
        { 
        if ($ctype.Name -eq "Custom") {

            If (!$AllContentTypes.Contains($contentType.Id))
            {
                $AllContentTypes += $contentType.Id;

                # Let's write on Content types CSV
                '"' + $contentType.Name + '","' + $contentType.Description + '","' + $contentType.Id + '","' + $contentType.Group + '","' + $contentType.Parent.Id + '"' | Out-File $CTS_FILE_PATH -Append

                ForEach ($field in $contentType.Fields)
                {
                    If (!$AllFields.Contains($field.Id))
                    {
                        $AllFields += $field.Id;

                         # Let's write on Fields CSV
                        '"' + $field.Title + '","' + $field.Description + '","' + $field.Id + '","' + $field.Group + '","' + $field.Type + '","' | Out-File $FIELDS_FILE_PATH -Append;
                    }

                    '"' + $contentType.Name + '","' + $field.Title + '","' + $contentType.Id + '","' + $field.Id + '","' | Out-File $CT_FIELDS_FILE_PATH -Append;
                }
            }
}
        }
    }
}
```

http://valeriovalrosso.blogspot.com/2013/03/get-site-content-types-and-site-columns.html

Comment: This creates all three files on the desktop but none of them contain any data. Just the headers. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it looping through the subsites? i.e. do you see "Extracting info from ..."

Comment: No it just sits after hitting enter to run. The three files show up right away but are never populated with any data besides the headers. I've even let it run for over an hour hoping it was doing something.